# How to show posts with multiple tags on tag.php?

Tags: loop, tags, slug

On my tag.php page, I want to show posts with multiple tags...

I have something like this:

mypage.com/tag/**tag1+tag2+tag3**/

```
$tags = get_queried_object()->slug; //returns only 'tag1' !!

$args = array( 
    'tag' => $tags //need to get 'tag1+tag2+tag3' here
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

Is there any other way how to show posts with multiple tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_query_var( 'tag' )` will return you `'tag1+tag2+tag3'` string.

`get_query_var( 'tag_slug__and' )` will return you the array of tags.

So, there are two ways to achieve the goal:

```
$args = array( 
    'tag' => get_query_var( 'tag' ), // string
);
```

or

```
$args = array( 
    'tag__and' => get_query_var( 'tag_slug__and' ), // array
);
```

It remains to be seen how do you plan to create `tag1+tag2+tag3` slug.